# Как получить содержимое iframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

И так есть [сайт](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/embed?height=1200&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Europe/Moscow&src=c3JqOWdvcHRmdG9rNGc4aWhlZDExYmVoNnNAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&color=%230B8043&showNav=1&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&pli=1)

На этом сайте есть таблица с расписанием, но всё это находиться в `iframe`° Как получить содержимое `iframe`? Решение с использованием Selenium мне не подходит. Для начала я написал такой код.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/embed?height=1200&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Europe/Moscow&src=c3JqOWdvcHRmdG9rNGc4aWhlZDExYmVoNnNAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&color=%230B8043&showNav=1&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&pli=1"
HEADERS = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"}


def get_html(url):
    html = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    return html

def get_content_iframe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    iframe = soup.find('iframe')
    print(iframe)


def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content_iframe(html.text)
    else:
        return None

parser()
```

Но он мне возвращает None (замена на `find_all` результата тоже не дало, что логично), в инспекторе iframe есть. Я искал решения в интернете, но ответа не нашёл. Принимаются любые решения без использования selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запустил ваш код, попробовал вывести значение `soup` и в самом конце вывило:

> Похоже, ваш браузер не поддерживает выполнение сценариев JavaScript, необходимых для правильного отображения этой страницы.
> Перейти к HTML-версии этой страницы можно по адресу:
> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/htmlembed?height=1200&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Europe/Moscow&src=c3JqOWdvcHRmdG9rNGc4aWhlZDExYmVoNnNAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&color=%230B8043&showNav=1&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&pli=1

Я поставил эту ссылку место вашей, и все получилось

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/htmlembed?height=1200&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Europe/Moscow&src=c3JqOWdvcHRmdG9rNGc4aWhlZDExYmVoNnNAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&color=%230B8043&showNav=1&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&pli=1"

HEADERS = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"}


def get_html(url):
    html = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    return html

def get_content_iframe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    iframe = soup.find_all("td", class_ = "event-eventInfo")
    for i in iframe:
        print(i.text)


def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content_iframe(html.text)
    else:
        return None

parser()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Всё работает!